# Sequence Converge or Diverge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Does the following sequence converge or diverge: 
$a_n=\frac{\sin{\left(n\right)}}{2^{n}}$? My initial thought was that any value of $n$ to $\sin$ will be less than $1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $|\frac{\sin(n)}{2^n}|\le \frac{1}{2^n}$

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right.

In general:

> If $x_n$ is a bounded sequence and $y_n \to 0$, then $x_n y_n \to 0$.

Here is a proof:

> If $|x_n| < M, |y_n-0| < \varepsilon/M$ for $n$ sufficiently large, then $|x_n y_n-0| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

the sequence  converge to $0$
because $-1\leq sin(n)\leq 1$, we get:
$$-\frac{1}{2^n}\leq \frac{sin(n)}{2^n}\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$$
as $n\to\infty$ we get:$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} -\frac{1}{2^n}\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{sin(n)}{n}\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\iff 0\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{sin(n)}{n}\leq 0$$, by squeeze we conclude that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{sin(n)}{n}=0$$, hence $(a_n)$ converges to $0$